# my android tablet isnt tworking

Tags: troubleshooting

I had a new tablet for Christmas and it worked properly. Today it just wasn't doing so well:

I turned on the power and swiped my finger on the screen to unlock it. Then,

- When I touch an app it said app isn't installed.
- Sometimes when I touch an app it would come on but just stay on the title screen.
- Other times on the homepage it will not let me swipe left to right but stay on the homepage.

When I went to settings and tried to click the reboot button, it froze. I cut it off and on and even hit the reset button a few times. This time I turn it off and turn it back on then the screen turn into something like a white faze and you would not see anything on the screen like something inside there is broken. Please give me some advice.

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose a problem with some basics about your device - which one, and what version of Android is it using?

Comment: Plus what the last things were you did before the trouble started. Maybe some new install?

Comment: - also `adb logcat` output when odd stuff is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, this leaves just two options:

- perform a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) (see the corresponding [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for details) and see whether that helps
- if a factory-reset doesn't bring it back to working order, send it for repair. Your warranty should still apply.